# How to check Flash Player is installed from Adobe Air application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I have an AIR application that needs check if the Flash Player is installed on Windows. I tried check through [`Capabilities.version`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version) method, but it's doesn't solve...

```
trace(Capabilities.version); // shows Adobe AIR version
```

I tried to use the [`HTMLLoader.swfCapability`](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#swfCapability), but for some reason it doesn't work... Always shows installed...

```
trace(HTMLLoader.swfCapability == HTMLSWFCapability.STATUS_OK); // always true
```

How can I detect if the Flash Player is installed on the PC from my AIR application?

Comment: Those ways will always show installed because they are run in the context of the AIR container/application - which obviously has a built in flash player.   For windows, you could probably query the registry and find out - though I'm not sure why you'd care if flash player is installed if you already have an AIR application that has it's own flash player.

Comment: You do not have to be sure. I just need to confirm that it is installed and Adobe AIR can not. How do I search for the registry? Is it possible to access it through Adobe AIR? Is that the only way?

Comment: Which Flash Player, actually? Standalone Flash Player? ActiveX component? Plugin for Mozilla? Plugin for Chrome? These I can think of, there might be more.

Comment: You can't access the registry through AIR directly, you'd have to create an ANE (Adobe Native Extension) that does the registry query and then interact with that ANE in AIR.

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis That or **NativeProcess**.

Comment: @Organis, None... The Flash Player is not installed. The program I want to check is the [NPAPI version](https://get.adobe.com/br/flashplayer/npapi/) (to be more specific).

Comment: @bio NPAPI is a Mozilla-compatible Flash Plugin.

Comment: @Organis Yes, It's this version... Some problem?

Comment: @bio Nope, just making the exact problem clear. Then, there are no simple solutions and probably there are no ready solutions for you. You need to create some (presumably C/C++) code that uses Windows Registry API (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875.aspx) and gets the data you want, then to make it into something console-line-ish and use via **NativeProcess**, or turn into DLL and then into ANE (preferably).

Comment: I did not want to have so much work, but I do not think I can get away ... I'll try to do something like that. Thanks for the comments @Organis and @BadFeelingAboutThis!

Comment: @bio The thing you want is weird to begin with. I cannot even think of an idea who would anyone want that. Checking from desktop application if user has Flash Player for FireFox. Which is useless without FireFox itself, and would also fail if user has Chrome, or Internet Explorer, or (probably) Edge.

Comment: I will try to explain well summarized. My application displays from several swfs using the `HTMLLoader` object over and over again. I use this object because of the difficulty in unloading the swfs after they are loaded with other objects, like `Loader`. Adobe AIR uses Flash Player NPAPI (the same as Firefox). For this reason I would like to know if FP is installed.